# How can I find the vertex of a parabola using only $x$ intercepts.

Tags: quadratics

My teacher gave me this problem where I did a long jump and recorded the distance I went. He then asked us the height. My distance was 80 inches so the x-intercepts are $0,0$ and $80,0$. My question Is how can I make a quadratic Equation using only the $x$ intercepts to find height.

Comment: please don't block I really need help

Comment: You need more information, such as perhaps the amount of strength for the jump, which would affect the acceleration.

Comment: You can't.  You need some other piece of information.  $-5x(x-80), -7x(x-80), -11x(x-80)$ all have those $x$-intercepts.

Comment: @JacobBond is there a way to make a quadratic equation with x intercepts then plug in the line of symmetry?

Comment: @ethangail: Knowing the $x$-intercepts is enough to find the line of symmetry, but it's not enough to determine the maximum height.

Answer (score 1):

You need additional data to find the height.

For example, the parabolas $y=-x^2+80x$ and $y=-2x^2+160x$ both have the $x$-intercepts you specify, but vertices at $(40,1600)$ and $(40,3200)$, respectively.

Comment: is there a way to plug in the line of symmetry? and how did you come up with those numbers I am only in 7th grade.

Comment: Knowing the x intercepts tells you the location of the line of symmetry: it's exactly halfway in between.  No matter what parabola you have, the vertex lies on the line of symmetry, and there are infinitely many parabolas that go through two given points.

Comment: @ethangail: I constructed the two examples as $-(x-0)(x-80)$ and $-2(x-0)(x-80)$ -- that is, the method MPW describes with $k=-1$ and $k=-2$, chosen negative such that the parabolas would open downward. As Dan describes the axis is always halfway between the x-intercepts, so I simply evaluated my two functions at $x=40$ to find their vertices.

Comment: Thank You, you are great at math! You really explained it well for me. If possible, could you explain more topics to me in the future?

Comment: what exactly does a computer scientist do?

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the $x$-intercepts doesn't completely determine the parabola. If the specified intercepts are $a$ and $b$, then every function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ with $f(x)=k(x-a)(x-b)$ has a graph that is a (possibly degenerate) parabola for which these values are intercepts.

But if, say, you also know another point $(u,v)$ that also lies on the parabola, the parabola is determined. That's because you can plug the coordinates into the equation for the parabola and find $k$ (set $x=u$ and set $f(x)=v$; this gives the equation $v=k(u-a)(u-b)$ to solve for $k$, right?).

Comment: could you explain this to me in the most basic way possible? @WMP I am only in 7th grade

Comment: I don't want an answer I just want to know how the math works

Answer (score 1):

While the height cannot possibly be determined from just the two $x$ intercepts, and you thus need more information, there are quite a few single pieces of additional information that *can* be used, especially since we know the strength of gravity, $386 in/s^2$. Here are a few:

- **A third point on the parabola** This one's pretty obvious; you find the parabola through the three points and the apex will fall right out.
- **Airtime** Interestingly, this is independent of the distance jumped, the height is equal to $gt^2/8$, about 48 inches upward for a jump of 1 second, and about 12 inches for a jump of 1/2 second.
- **Angle of liftoff** The formula of the parabola is then $\tan\theta\cdot x \cdot (d-x)/d$, which gives a vertex height of $d\tan\theta/4$.  In your case, for $\theta=45^\circ$ that's 20 inches upward; for a shallower $\theta=14^\circ$ it's 5 inches.  This works out the same for angle of landing.
- **Ground speed during the leap** You can use this and the standard speed formula to find the time spent airborne, making this equivalent to the airtime method.
- **Airspeed at liftoff** This is the hardest.  Given the airspeed, you can find the target angle of firing as $$\theta =\frac{\arcsin\left(\frac{gd}{v^2}\right)}{2}$$ which you can then use in the angle of liftoff method.  Interestingly, you actually get two possible angles, the $\theta$ found above, and $90^\circ-\theta$.  The latter gives a higher apex.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, you need to know three points on the parabola to determine it uniquely. The general form of a parabola is $ax^2 + bx + c$, which is three unknowns, which means we need three linear relations (given by three points on the curve) to determine it. Just knowing the x-intercepts does not give enough information to determine all three coefficients.

Comment: could you plug in random numbers?

Comment: @ethangail No, because depending on the random number you choose, you would get different answers. There are infinitely many solutions to "which quadratic curve passes through the points $(0,0)$ and $(0,80)$. $f(x) = kx(x-80)$ is a solution for **any** value of $k$ you choose.

Comment: so really All I have to do is find numbers that work.

Comment: @ethangail If you just want to find **a** parabola, yes. Then you can pick any value of $k$ you want, and it will work.